# Time complexity question asked in interview

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, data-structures, time-complexity

```
int[] a = {3,5,4,3,2,2,1};

        System.out.println("Duplicate elements are: ");

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
                if(a[i]==a[j]  && i!=j){
                    System.out.println(a[j] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
```

This codes time complexity is O(n^2), interviewer asked me to change it to O(n). How can we do that?

Comment: What is supposed to be done here: `//do something in constant time`? Both loops increment from `zero` to `n`. Why do you even need the inner loop?

Comment: It's not possible to do it without knowing what's inside the nested loop. Might become O(1) at the end, might be O(n) or it might stay at O(n²).

Comment: Well, if the something is e.g., filling a matrix with values,e.g.,  `m[i][j] = i*j` then this is not possible

Comment: i have updated the code in my question. It is exact same question. Can you now elaborate about it?

Comment: @RyanWilson check the updated version of code now. can you tell me now how can we do that?

Comment: @EricDuminil check the updated version of code now. can you tell me now how can we do that?

Comment: The point of the interview question is (at least) two-fold. The first thing you have to do is figure out what the code does. Did you do that? Once you figure out what the code does, then you can figure out a way to do it more efficiently.

Comment: We need more information. For example, if the values are positive and less than `n` as in your example, then you can implement a counting sort

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution which would meet the `O(n)` requirement, that would be to use a `HashSet` - A `HashSet` will not accept a duplicate value, so one loop is all you need, that is if the requirements allow for use of a declared `HashSet`:

```
int[] a = {3,5,4,3,2,2,1};
// Create a set 
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
//Create a set for storing duplicates
Set<Integer> setDupes = new HashSet<Integer>();

System.out.println("Duplicate elements are: ");

//loop the array once 
for (int num : a) 
{ 
     if (set.add(num) == false) 
     { 
        // your duplicate element
        if(setDupes.add(num) == true) 
           System.out.println(num + " ");
     } 
}
```

Comment: After looking at the question again, I think you're right. The OP wasn't specific, and I made some wrong assumptions. I have deleted my comments.

Comment: @JimMischel No problem Jim. I think you were only trying to help and teach me something. I have no problem with that. To be honest, I spent about 2 days off and on when I had free time, trying to come up with a better solution, I unfortunately was unable to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do inside the loop. If they are not dependent then you can merge both of them in one

Comment: check the updated version of code now. can you tell me now how can we do that?

Answer (score -3):

When the loops are not dependent you can re-write the loop as:

```
    for (int i = 0, j=0; i < n && j<n; i++;j++) {
        //do something in constant time
    }
```

Comment: We don't know that the loops are independent. What if the constant time thing is something like `intArray[i][j] = 0;`?

Comment: @azurefrog I sometimes wonder if posts like this are done purposefully to try and add reputation from one account to another or to both accounts via the same user.

Comment: @RyanWilson smells like a tinfoil

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino It smells of something...:P Especially since the OP doesn't seem to be responsive, nor the people posting answers.

Comment: check the updated version of code now. can you tell me now how can we do that?